# Keep URL for file, but change directory?

Tags: .htaccess, symlink

I have a file hosted at `http://example.com/old-directory/document.pdf`.

I'm not able to change the link, but I need to change the directory the file is downloaded from.

Current dir

`/my/web/server/current/files/document.pdf`

New dir

`/my/web/server/new/files/document.pdf`

What's the best method of changing the directory without changing the URL with PHP/Apache?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.htaccess` to remap that location to a different directory (or just that file).

Create a `.htaccess` file and use this syntax to "redirect" the file:

```
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html /newdirectory/newfile.html
```

This will send the new file instead of the old one when accessed.

If you need to do something more specific, [this generator](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/) will work fine.

Comment: This surely changes the scope of the question, but I have hundreds of files organized into date-based directories. 1) I don't want to manually configure each and 2) I don't know which sub-directory a file is in. Is there a way to define `/newdir/files/` as the root even if the file is actually in `/olddir/files/2013/05/`?

Comment: @developdaly Have a look at the generator I linked.

Comment: @developdaly Revisiting this question - htaccess has a method of remapping one directory to another, however, depending on how you are hosting your site, it would be better to do it some other way.